# Android BuildConfig String with Json

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, auto-generate, android-buildconfig

I'd like to have a JSON formatted String in the buildConfig but the build process messes the string up and I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "testkey1": "someValue1",
    "testkey2": 3,
    "testkey3": {
        "innerKey1": "innerValue1",
        "innerKey2": "innerValue2"
    }
}
```

In my gradle file I have the following (Android Studio adds escapes)

```
buildConfigField "String", "JSON", "\"{\"testkey1\": \"someValue1\",\"testkey2\": 3,\"testkey3\": {\"innerKey1\": \"innerValue1\",\"innerKey2\": \"innerValue2\"}}\""
```

What it compiles (auto-generates) from the above is

```
public static final String JSON = "{"testkey1": "someValue1","testkey2": 3,"testkey3": {"innerKey1": "innerValue1","innerKey2": "innerValue2"}}";
```

The problem is that all the escapes are missing in the generated code. This is not a valid String. It should be more like this

```
public static final String JSON = "{\"testkey1\": \"someValue1\",\"testkey2\": 3,\"testkey3\": {\"innerKey1\": \"innerValue1\",\"innerKey2\": \"innerValue2\"}}";
```

But how?

Comment: `\"` => `\\\"` ? now you are only escaping them for gradle ... off-topic comment: use file resource instead buildConfig

Comment: try beginning and ending the entire string with `'` instead of `\"`. But using a file resource name is better solution, as Selvin mentioned

Comment: can you drop me a link to some info about file resources?

Comment: just put a text files into assets, each of which contains different variants of JSON you need for different builds. In `buildConfigField` put the names of those files instead. And wherever you need to use that JSON - load it from the file by the name in `BuildConfig`